# Find local processes starting TCP connections

Tags: linux, tcp, ipv4

With tcpdump I see many SYN packets ... and source IP is Localhost.

I wish to find which processes are trying to connect.

Note the connections don't reach ESTABLISHED state, they seems to be random port scans.

Comment: For what OS? Kernel tracing tools on e.g. Solaris (DTrace) or Linux (SystemTap, etc) may provide insight.

Comment: @thrig linux, and I am ignorant about systemtap

Comment: it is a linux instance on AWS, and the culprit is " curl -s -f http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/06:84:40:71:c9:e5/local-ipv4"

Comment: who is running this and why ?

Comment: When you say "source IP is Localhost", do you mean 127.0.0.1? Or the the IP address of the host on any of the system's network interface other than the loopback one (`lo`)? On what interface did you run that `tcpdump` on ?

Comment: Add an audit watch on the execve() system call or enable process accounting (`acton`...`lastcomm`) if you want to see what spawns those `curl` commands.

Answer (score 3):

I've been in the same situation recently on Linux (the culprit was `adb`). My approach was to use the audit system to log the `connect()` system calls.

```
sudo auditctl -a exit,always  -F arch=b64  -S connect -k who-connects
```

To tell the audit system to log all `connect()` system calls (here the 64bit variant, you can add another one for the 32 bit variants if you're on a multi-arch system with both 32 and 64 bit applications)

Later run:

```
sudo ausearch -i -k who-connects
```

To see what made connections.

It would still be possible to make TCP connections without using the socket API. For instance by implementing a TCP stack in user space and using lower level APIs to send packets, but that would not be common (especially on  the loopback interface).

Comment: I issue "sudo su -" then auditctl with arch=b64  and auditctl with arch=b32; ausearch prints two identical lines without arch and with auid user not root : is it right ?

Comment: type=CONFIG_CHANGE msg=audit(05/21/2017 20:21:05.954:135) : auid=USER ses=12 op="add_rule" key=who-connects list=exit res=yes

Comment: @Massimo, that's the log entries for the auditctl commands you did (which  do change the audit configuration). If there's nothing else, that would mean there's not been any connect() system call.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have SystemTap installed

```
probe begin {
    printf("ok\n");
}
probe syscall.connect {
    # connect however may fail or flail around in a EINPROGRESS state;
    # this log only indicates that a connect was attempted
    if (uaddr_af == "AF_INET" || uaddr_af == "AF_INET6")
        printf("%s[%d]: %s\n", execname(), pid(), argstr);
}
probe syscall.connect.return {
    printf(" -> %s[%d]: %s\n", execname(), pid(), retstr);
}
```

saved as `whomakeconnect.stp` will show `connect` calls when run with `stap` as `root`

```
# stap-prep
... fix anything reported, it requires debug kernels ...
# stap whomakeconnect.stp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use netstat cammand. It shows the state of the packet. But you have to catch the output, because it only seems at sending time. It is not like a tcp listening socket. That's why you can ty to catch it by using watch command. I suppose that the connection is over ipv4.

```
watch -n 0.1 'netstat -4pn | grep -F "SYN_SENT"'
```

nestat flags

p flag: process id/name

n flag: numeric output (no dns resolution)

4 flag: show ipv4 sockets

watch command makes netstat command run repetitive with 0.1 second period.