# IS there a means of identifying the application path for the process which attempts to access the internet on a linux distributution?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, tcp-ip

Is there a means (kernel mode API) under Linux (any distro) that can identify the application path of a process that makes a connect() call and is attempting to access the internet ? Vice versa in the same respect if the application is attempting to receive a TCP data packet is it possible to identify the process that is receiving the packet? I need to be able to map and log programmatically such details whether the process is executing in kernel or user mode.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish, there are a few ways. You can look at the output of `netstat -nap` to see which processes are bound to what ports. You can also use the `lsof` command to see what processes have ports open. Another method is to have auditing turned on and configure its rules to log system calls and a host of other items.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366376/find-local-processes-starting-tcp-connections

Comment: @Deathgrip trying to map each and every TCP packet (received/sent) or an entire stream to a process whether the process is executing in user or kernel mode. I also need to be able to do this programmatically. I want to be able to log these details. Does this help ?

Comment: @thrig thank you. But can systemtap be interfaced programmatically via API and can it map a single TCP data packet (received or being sent) by a process or application whether this process is executing in kernel or user mode ?

Comment: You don't need to look at packets at all; you just need to look at what sockets are open.

Comment: @psusi I would like to be able to map and log each packet with an application or process that's associated with it.

Comment: Yes, it is. But what do you want to do with it? Doing something with every packet quickly gets prohibitively expensive. Doing something only on the `connect` call, and not on every `receive` call, would be more reasonable.

Comment: @Gilles I need to be able to log such information and details and also prevent such traffic if the application path or process is not on the list of known and accepted applications and or processes.